# LDAP web interface for managing password used by dovecot

Tags: ldap

With dovecot, it's possible to [verify passwords via LDAP with authentication binds](https://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/AuthBinds).

**I am looking for a web interface solution which features following:**

The administrator creates all user accounts in LDAP and sets a preliminary password for each account. Each user should be able to change their own account password over a website with access to LDAP. So, only the password is writeable by the respective user and nothing else. The same password is used to access mail server via SMTP and IMAP and login into the website.

Note: For security reasons, it should not require a web server running on the same server as the mail server (as e.g. PostfixAdmin does).

Comment: What is used at SMTP side? If Postfix, maybe PostfixAdmin (a web tool) could be used.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the feedback. Currently, I am using postfix on my old server. Postfixadmin seemed to me to be too bloated. But, if I am able to limit the capabilities only to changing passwords, I might give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, postfixadmin cannot be used as it requires the webserver to be running on the same server as the mailserver, which I don't want to do due to security reasons.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that limitation. To avoid others tapping into the same trap, I took the freedom to add that to your question. Sorry my suggestion didn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [web2ldap](https://web2ldap.de) for this. Being the author I'm biased of course.

Its input forms can be customized with very simple [HTML templates](https://www.web2ldap.de/usability.html#html_templates). And you can add new entries based on simple [LDIF templates](https://www.web2ldap.de/usability.html#ldif_templates), e.g. specifying parent DN and object classes.

Furthermore you can construct [bookmarks](https://www.web2ldap.de/usability.html#persistent_bookmarks) for directly pointing a LDAP user to password change form.

P.S.: Are you already running an LDAP server and loaded it with data? Which schema for mail accounts are you using?

Comment: Thanks :). I am still considering my options. Basically, I want to store the password in an encrypted form on a server that is queried by Dovecot and replies with a success or fail message. Dovecot never gets to see the correct passwords.

Comment: So you don't have a running LDAP server yet and you're starting from scratch?

Comment: Yes. Everything is still in the open. I am currently using Postfix and Dovecot together with a relay server, provided by my webhoster. Now, I would like to setup everything myself.

Comment: I'm using my  [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com) also for maintaining mail accounts with aliases and simple mail groups. There are config examples for _postfix_ and _dovecot_ in the git repo.